# Optimization - Managing urls via htaccess or php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, optimization

I'm working on an e-commerce website's architecture and I'd like some help optimizing my url management. I'm hesitating between :

- a very little htaccess containing only : `RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]+)/?([-a-z0-9]*)$ index.php?page=$1&produit=$2` with a more or less big global index.php file which contains lots of conditions for the includes
- a big htaccess which manages more cases and guides the php, meaning php is containing less conditions running at every view on the site.

I read that htaccesses are slowing down the server so I chose option one, but I'm still hesitating. Which option is better? Are there more (and better) alternatives to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to code in modules and sub modules. This will result in a max of 3 rewrite rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?mod=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?mod=$1&sub=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?mod=$1&sub=$2&detail=$3 [L]
```

You can use module Catalog, submodule Article and detail Product
Also module Catalog can use submodule Category, etc.

In this way you're able to create a whole shopping system with just 3 lines of rewrite rules.

Hope this is what you where searching for :)

Comment: Thank you Joran :)
Even if you seem to work at Google and I trust you :
Anybody wants to complete this topic with useful tips ?